# undefined reference to `std::filesystem::__cxx11

Tags: reference, undefined

My gcc version is 9.4.0, Clang 7.0.1 and C++17.

```
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
  auto const path_of_friend = fs::absolute( "path/friend" );
}
```

And I am getting the error "undefined reference to `std::filesystem::absolute".
What must I do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found this: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/issues/6889#issuecomment-878552846.

Looks like `stdc++fs` is needed in some distro.